# How to set .NET project name not to the name of the project folder

Tags: .net, directory, project

Is there any way to create a new project where the project folder has a different name than the project itself?

I know how to do this by an existing project by changing the namespace, the projectfile name and content and if necessary, the exe file name, but how can I do this for a new project without the "overhead"?

I wan to create all my new .NET projects in a _Main folder for the main branch of the project and then branch, if necessary to the _Release folder within the TFS team project for this .NET project.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want to create a project inside a different folder other than the root. To accomplish that you can add a new folder path when you are at the Add Project screen.
Like this:

[image]

Comment: No, in your example, VS creates an additional folder.
In your example \CustomFolderName\AnotherFolder ...
-CustomFolderName
|- AnotherFolder
|-- AnotherFolder.csproj

I need this:
_Main
|- AnotherFolder.csproj

Comment: So, what are you asking doesnt make sense, because every project needs to have its own folder, otherwise the project folders like bin, obj would be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible but I do not know how to do it with Visual Studio.
Right now I have to change the (project) files, references, namespace and project folder manually and then it works.

[image]